# checkbox buttons hidden status after page refresh

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a form with checkbox toggle buttons (using twitter bootstrap and Rails)

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> Option 2
  </label>
</div>
```

I click and choose `Option 1`. Then I refresh the page. When the page is refreshed all the buttons are reset and `Option 1` is not selected any more. However if I go ahead and submit the form, `Option 1` is sent to the server as if it was selected (checked). Is this a bug? Is this because of something in cookie. If yes, how can I check the cookie and find the ones that should be pressed and the command to change their status to pressed.

I have text fields (`<input type='text'>`) in the form as well. If I write in the text fields and refresh the page, the texts stay. It seems somewhere behind the scenes the state of the buttons stay as checked, too, but on the display I see them as un-checked. Therefore although the checkbox buttons seem to be un-checked when I submit the form they get submitted as checked.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure? Is this the html output or are you generating the form with erb or slim?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I am using a .html.erb file. I have text fields (`<input type='text'>`) in the form as well. If I write in the text fields and refresh the page, the texts stay. It seems somewhere behind the scenes the state of the buttons stay as checked, too, but on the display I see them as un-checked. Therefore although the checkbox buttons seem to be un-checked when I submit the form they get submitted as checked.

Comment: That's strange check the source code in your browser after the reload maybe, to check the value of the checkboxes, do you have a this up somewhere and can you share it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best solution but it's a start: reset the buttons after page refresh:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').button('reset');
});
```